# firebase database read and write permission denied

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read and write on firebase database from web application
and i got this error
[image: the error appear when the writeUserData() function called]
the error appear when the writeUserData() function called

and this is the js code

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.1/firebase.js"></script>`
`<script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
        // copied from firebase website
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    writeUserData();
    function writeUserData() {
        firebase.database().ref('options/gK6YJVMAr82Pp8GHmjJa').set({
            active_table: '2222',
        });
    }
</script>`

and this is the firebase database rules
[image: this is the rules]

And this is the database structure 
[image: this is the data structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing-up the two database types offered by Firebase: The Real Time Database and Firestore.

You are storing your data (and writing your security rules) in Firestore but the code you are using for writing data (`firebase.database().ref('options/gK6YJVMAr82Pp8GHmjJa').set()`) corresponds to the Real Time Database.

You will find here the documentation to write data to Firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

So in your case you should do something along theses lines:

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
db.collection("options").doc("gK6YJVMAr82Pp8GHmjJa").set({
            active_table: '2222',
        })
.then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
});
```

---

Note the use of `firebase.firestore()` instead of `firebase.database()`.